# routerLinkActive doesn't work inside nested router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have following templates

**app**:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**articles**:

```
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="./category/all" routerLinkActive="active">
          All Categories
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['./category', category.id]" routerLinkActive="active">
          {{category.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**articles-list**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-2">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/articles/category', categoryId, 'best']" routerLinkActive="active">
      Best
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/articles/category', categoryId, 'latest']" routerLinkActive="active">
      Latest
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and router config:

```
  {
    path: 'articles',
    component: ArticlesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'articles/category/all/best/all/page/0',
      },
      {
        path: 'articles/category/:categoryId',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'articles/category/:categoryId/best/all/page/0',
      },
      {
        path: 'articles/category/:categoryId/:sortOrder',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'articles/category/:categoryId/:sortOrder/all/page/0',
      },
      {
        path: 'articles/category/:categoryId/:sortOrder/:filter/page/:page',
        component: ArticlesListComponent,
        resolve: {
          page: ArticleResolver
        }
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      categories: CategoriesResolver
    }
  }
```

For some reason when I navigate through links in **articles** template "Best" link in **articles-list** template doesn't become active. However, it become active once page reloaded.

Why link doesn't change it's status to active and is there the way to solve this issue? Thanks.

**Edit:** My code on [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9PbITFctdokjdO8L16UI?p=preview)

Comment: `pathMatch: 'full'` is only required for routes with an empty path (`path: '',`) when the route doesn't have child routes.

Comment: I would create a new component for each option (best, latest, etc) and hold the category id as a variable in the parent. I'm sure there is a way to make it work your way, but it is complicated.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out why it's not working, but my answer was wrong. `exact: true` is rather the opposite of what you want, but I misunderstand the problem at first. Could be a bug.

Comment: Same issue to me. Has anyone found any solutions ?